# flutter build apk failure

Tags: android, flutter

Can succeed without him（sy_flutter_qiniu_storage）

Below is my error message

[image]

[image]

this flutter doctor -v

```sh
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287,
    locale en-CN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3.4)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: Alright, thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Check the Flutter qiniu Storage package documentation for something that could be wrong with the package itself